# Schedule Sql queries on hosted MySQl server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, schedule

I have MySQl server hosted on Amazon RDS. I access it through MySql workbench. I want to schedule queries on this, since it is on RDS i do not have super user permissions and i cannot create even schedulers. Can anyone suggest any solution for the same.Thanks

Comment: By "schedulers" do you mean MySQL `EVENT`s ?

Comment: yes. I cannot use event schedulers.